# Unable to Push Metadata to Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx

I've pulled all of my production org's metadata into the Force.com IDE and have been using it to publish customizations without issue.  I successfully migrated everything from Force.com to a Salesforce DX project, but I am unable to push it to a scratch org.  I'm presented with numerous errors such as "field not found" (which suggests the dependent custom objects were not pushed), but as there are so many errors I am unable to see the source of the failures.  I can successfully push new projects to a scratch org, but anytime I try to push existing code it fails.  Has anyone had success pushing existing code to a scratch org and if so what is the trick to overcoming the errors?

Comment: We need to see a lot more details about your error before we can even attempt to help. Your question is way too broad as it is.

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting so many errors I can't narrow it down (i.e. nearly everything is failing).  Basically, it's running into issues publishing metadata.  For example, something is stopping an object and/or custom fields from being pushed which causing failures further down the line:
"Invalid field Request_Reason__c for SObject Order".  Order should already exist in a scratch org so I'm not sure why associated custom fields are failing.

Comment: The trick would be to take this in steps.  Trim down your project to a small enough size to get it working and then slowly build it back up.  For instance, make a project holding only the Order object and try publishing only that no code.  If you get that working, add a piece of code that doesn't reference other code.  And thus build it back up.

Comment: Hmm...tried that and I couldn't even get a single object to push successfully.  At some point I'll be pulling in an object that has enough dependencies that the system can't resolve them during a push to the scratch org and fails.  Even if I could get it to work with this method, it doesn't seem feasible to do every time I need to spin up a scratch org.  I'm struggling to see the benefit of using Salesforce DX over Force.com IDE.

Comment: @Paugh Have you managed to resolve it?

Comment: @Json, no.  I spoke with someone at the TrailheaDX conference in March and he said to report it as a bug to the Salesforce DX team.